# Android .jar inside module

Tags: android, jar, module, gradle, dependencies

I'm new in the world Gradle. 
I created the form "MyApp" and the module "Library". 
Inside the module "Library" I have a. Jar inside the Libs folder and inside I build.gradle:

```
  dependencies {
     compile FileTree (dir: 'libs', includes: ['*. jar']) 
}
```

But the. Jar goes into error during compilation: 
Error: (108, 9) error: can not find symbol class JAXBContext.

What is wrong? 
thanks

Comment: What jars?JAXBContext is not a part of android

Comment: JAXBContext.jar is a. Jar that is inside the module "Library" (secondary module). The problem is that the main module "MyApp" is as if he could not reach it. 
How can you put a. Jar in module and use it in another?